# Looping in python: NameError: name 'df2' is not defined

Tags: python, pandas

I am tring to make changes to the multiple excel files. I have below program to loop through multiple files. I strangle get this error `NameError: name 'df2' is not defined`. Can someone help me to understand what is the issue? Thank you in advance!

```
import os
import glob
import pandas as pd
from pathlib import Path
folder = (r"C:\Users\Documents\Extracted")

for file_name in Path(folder).glob('*.xlsx'):
    df = pd.read_excel(file_name)
    drop_list = ['BarrierFreeAttributes.BarrierFreeAttribute','ConsultationHours.ConsultationHoursTimeSpan', 'Location.Coordinates.Latitude_right', 'Location.Coordinates.Longitude_right']
    if all(item in drop_list for item in list(df.columns)):
         df2 = df.drop(columns=drop_list, axis=1)
    else:
        print(file_name)
        df2.to_excel(file_name.with_suffix('.xlsx'),index = False)
```

Data:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Reason is in `else` is not defined `df2`, simpliest is use `df` only and overwrite it in `if` statement, also writing to file is removed from `else` statement:

```
for file_name in Path(folder).glob('*.xlsx'):
    df = pd.read_excel(file_name)
    drop_list = ['BarrierFreeAttributes.BarrierFreeAttribute','ConsultationHours.ConsultationHoursTimeSpan', 'Location.Coordinates.Latitude_right', 'Location.Coordinates.Longitude_right']
    if all(item in drop_list for item in list(df.columns)):
         df = df.drop(columns=drop_list, axis=1)
    else:
        print(file_name)

    df.to_excel(file_name.with_suffix('.xlsx'),index = False)
```

Comment: Hi, Thank you! If I overwrite it works but doesn't drop the columns that I wanted to drop.

Comment: @ChKYu - So need `'shift'` `df.to_excel(file_name.with_suffix('.xlsx'),index = False)` for write after `if` or `else` ? Answer was edited.

Comment: I realise its nothing to do with the code. The code works correctly but still it doesn't drop the variables. I would like to give a bit of background of the data. This is the data extracted from web json file. I have the variables in this format with (.) dot in between the variable names as in ```drop_list``` in the program. Do you this this could be the reason the program is unable to drop the variables.

Comment: @ChKYu - if check `print (all(item in drop_list for item in list(df.columns)))` it return True correctly? Because it seems data related problem.

Comment: I see it returns False. But I don't understand why, do you think that's because the way variables there in the data? I have copied the screenshot of dataset how it look like.

Comment: I see the problem is because I am writing/exporting to the same location where I am reading/importing the files from. But I am not sure where in df.to_excel to make changes.